# Show that two definition of Independent Random Variables are Equivalent

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, independence

I want to show that X and Y, two random variables, are independent iff $P(X=x, Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)$

The definition of independent random variables is $P(X\leq x, Y \leq y)=P(X\leq x)P(Y\leq y)$

I've already done this for the continuous random variable case but now discrete is causing my problems.  I showed that $P(X=x, Y=y)=P(X=x)P(Y=y)$ implies independence by taking the double sum for all values less than x and y respectively to get the CDFs.

I have problems going the other way though.  I've tried taking the limits on both sides of the equations for the CDFs to obtain the pmfs, but the equation doesn't work out nicely I get too many values on the right hand side.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint, for discrete RV: $$P(X{=}x, Y{=}y) \,=\, P(X{\leq}x, Y{\leq}y) - P(X{<} x, Y{\leq}y) - P(X{\leq}x, Y {<} y)+ P(X{<}x, Y{<}y)$$

Comment: This is exactly the thing I needed to make the argument work, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Fix some $x$ and $y$.

If the random variables are discrete, then we have
\begin{align}
P(X \le x, Y \le y) &= P(X \le x) P(Y \le y)
\\
P(X \le x, Y < y) &= P(X \le x) P(Y < y)
\\
P(X < x, Y \le y) &= P(X < x) P(Y \le y)
\\
P(X < x, Y < y) &= P(X < x) P(Y < y)
\end{align}

Subtracting the second line from the first gives $P(X \le x, Y=y) = P(X \le x) P(Y=y)$. Subtracting the fourth line from the third gives $P(X<x, Y = y) = P(X<x) P(Y =y)$. Subtracting these two equations gives the desired condition.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ be a probability space. Two sub-$\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal G,\mathcal H\subset \mathcal F$ are independent if for all $A\in\mathcal G$, $B\in\mathcal H$, we have
$$\mathbb P(A\cap G) = \mathbb P(A)\mathbb P(B). $$

This definition extends to random variables $X$, $Y$, by considering the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable:
$$\sigma(X) = \{X^{-1}(B):B\in\mathcal B \} $$
where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb R$, i.e. the intersections of all $\sigma$-algebras that contain the open intervals $(a,b)$. We say that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $\sigma(X)$ and $\sigma(Y)$ are independent, that is, for all $E\in\sigma(X)$, $F\in\sigma(Y)$ we have
$$\mathbb P(\{X\in A\}\cap\{Y\in B\}) = \mathbb P(X\in A)\mathbb P(Y\in A). $$
In the case of discrete random variables, we have e.g. $\{X=x\}, \{X\leqslant x\}\in\sigma(X)$, so the equivalence you want to show follows directly from the definition of independence.